# How to add conditions in directive for ng-class angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a 'p' tag inside a directive which needs to show and hide based on response and some click events. I am trying to achieve this using ng-class. I added ng-class on conditional basis, but due to single and double quotes, it is throwing an error.

How to properly assign the quotes for conditional ng-class inside a directive.

```
ng-class="{'show hide ': $index > 2 && myJSON.count > 4}"
```

this is what I tried:

```
angular.module('mydirective').directive('test'),
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                myJSON: '=myJSON'
            },
            template: '<p class="content" ng-repeat="abc in myJSON" ng-class="{'show hide ': $index > 2 && myJSON.count > 4}"></p>'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('mydirective').directive('test'),
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myJSON: '=myJSON'
        },
        template: '<p class="content" ng-repeat="abc in myJSON" ng-class="{\'show hide\': $index > 2 && myJSON.count > 4}"></p>'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good option will be to use the templateUrl and move the HTML code to separate file. This will get ride of the quotes issue.